# Understanding Matlab transformation matrix (tform.T)

Tags: matlab, matrix, transformation

what I'm trying to do is working with an Matlab `2-D projective geometric transformation`. The actual transformation is working pretty great, but I don't really understand the transformation matrix in terms of what the number/values of each item stands for.

My transformation matrix is of type `tform.T` and is a `3 x 3` matrix for `2D` transformation. The object is described in the [official documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/projective2d-class.html)  E.g.:

```
K>> tform.T
ans =
    1.6558    0.0476         0
   -0.0476    1.5880         0
    6.0775   14.7415    1.0000
```

so far I recognized that the last column is every time `[0,0,1]`. But what the other numbers stands for? So far I didn't found any proper documentation (maybe because it's so easy that everyone is presupposed the theory of a transformation matrix?)

Comment: Probably this has nothing to do with matlab. You may ask  it in math stack.

Answer (score 2):

The last column is always `[0;0;1]` because it is a 2D transform. In a 3D transform this would be the `z` direction transformation.

The other two columns describe the `x` and `y` direction transformations, as specified in the "proper documentation" which *you* linked to! As stated there, the relation holds that

```
[x y 1] = [u v 1] * T
```

Where `T` has the form

```
T = [a b c 
     d e f
     g h i];
```

So, using standard matrix multiplication,

```
x = g + a*u + d*v
y = h + b*u + e*v
1 = i + c*u + f*v = 1 + 0 + 0
```

This is the very nature of the transformation, where `x` and `y` are your newly transformed coordinates from the input `u` and `v`.